# Linq query based on the condition

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

I have to check col1 , col2 and col3 values and select the correct linq query.

This is how i am doing using if conditions.

```
 public DataTable GetRawData(string col1, string col2, string col3)
        {
            IQueryable<IF_Table> result = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id");
            dt.Columns.Add("DetailId");
            dt.Columns.Add("Description");
            DataRow row = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col1))
            {
                 result = db.IF_Table.Where(x => x.col1 == col1);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col2))
            {
                result = db.IF_Table.Where(x => x.col2 == col2);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col3))
            {
                result = db.IF_Table.Where(x => x.col3 == col3);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(col2))
            {
                result = db.IF_Table.Where(x => x.col1 == col1 && x.col2==col2);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(col3))
            {
                result = db.IF_Table.Where(x => x.col1 == col1 && x.col3 == col3);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col2) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(col3))
            {
                result = db.IF_Table.Where(x => x.col2 == col2 && x.col3 == col3);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(col2) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(col3))
            {
                result = db.IF_Table.Where(x =>x.col1==col1 && x.col2 == col2 && x.col3 == col3);
            }
            foreach ( var rowObj in result)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(rowObj.Id, rowObj.DetailId,rowObj.Description);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Is there any other way to do without using too many if conditions? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: You need [expression tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define base query which will return `db.IF_Table`. After that build the query around this result. This 3 `if` on your result should cover all of your cases.

```
        IQueryable<IF_Table> result = db.IF_Table;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col1))
        {
             result = result.Where(x => x.col1 == col1);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col2))
        {
            result = result.Where(x => x.col2 == col2);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col3))
        {
            result = result.Where(x => x.col3 == col3);
        }
```

If you want empty `DataTable` to be return when all col1, col2, col3 are empty string or null. You can define bool variable `fillTable` and set it to `true` in the if statements. After the ifs you can check `if(!fillTable)return dt;`